# Login to PalPal interface in Android in Sand Box environment

Tags: android

i have integrated the PayPal in to my Android App.
But as i click on the yellow color "Pal with PayPal" button a interface in web view opens
where it requres paypal user name and password.
But login fails, i tried this with 2-3 paypal ids.
I am running the App in PayPal SandBox environment and using the Test AppId for PayPal.
Can you please help me by telling how can i log in to the paypal activity in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made a PayPal Sandbox account? From my understanding, you need to use a special test account that you get from [PayPal Sandox](http://developer.paypal.com). Click on the signup button, and I'm sure you can figure it out from there. As far as I know, these test accounts are the only accounts that will work when testing.

Comment: ya i have created a test account then also unable to login .

Comment: ya i m able to log into the screen but session expires many times during login process.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an specialist, just go to developer.paypal.com
Here is all full explained: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_Sandbox_User_Guide.pdf

Cheers!